# How Can I remove an item from ConcurrentHashMap when no have a thread holding certain object anymore?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking

Supposing I have a temporary collection (ConcurrentHashMap) to hold a reference for a certain object, e.g., a HttpSession. While at least one thread is using a session (in the moment of a request), it can't be removed. But, when no more threads are using a session concurrently, it should be removed to release memory. I tried implement a example similar to that, but I got a NullPointerException. What I'm doing wrong? :(

```
    class Elem {
      // AtomicInteger saldo = new AtomicInteger(1000);
      Integer saldo = 1000;
    }

    class Sum implements Runnable {

    Map<String, Elem> saldos;
    AtomicInteger n;

    public Sum(Map<String, Elem> saldos, AtomicInteger n) {
        this.saldos = saldos;
        this.n = n;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        Random rand = new Random();

        int r = rand.nextInt(1000);

        Elem e = this.saldos.get("saldo");

        //Null Pointer Exception occurs here!
        synchronized (e) {

            this.n.incrementAndGet();

            if (r % 2 == 0) {

                Integer saldoLido = e.saldo;

                e.saldo += r;

                Integer saldoAtual = e.saldo;

                System.out.println("saldo lido: " + saldoLido + " somado: " + r
                                   + " saldo atual: " + (saldoAtual) + " "
                                   + System.currentTimeMillis());

            } else {

                Integer saldoLido = e.saldo;

                e.saldo -= r;

                Integer saldoAtual = e.saldo;

                System.out.println("saldo lido: " + saldoLido + " subtraído: "
                                   + r + " saldo atual: " + (saldoAtual) + " "
                                   + System.currentTimeMillis());
            }


             if(this.n.decrementAndGet() == 0)
                 this.saldos.remove("saldo");

        }

    }

    }

    public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Map<String, Elem> saldos = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(20, 0.9f, 1);

        AtomicInteger n = new AtomicInteger(0);

        saldos.put("saldo", new Elem());

        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);

        try {

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
                exec.execute(new Sum(saldos, n));

            exec.shutdown();

            while (!exec.isTerminated()) {}

            System.out.println("got elem: " + saldos.get("saldo") + " " + n);

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            exec.shutdownNow();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    }
```

Comment: On what line was the NPE?

Comment: On line with "synchronized (e)"... I want that when n (number of concurrent threads) reaches value 0, the session being removed! (immediate realizing of memory)! Sorry I not good dealing with concurrency :(

Comment: Use a java.util.WeakHashMap.

Comment: Good point! But WeakHashMap releases memory soon as possible right? I want release memory soon as all threads using a object unlock it!

Comment: Sometimes I run the code above and no NPE occurs, but sometimes it occurs !

Comment: `WeakHashMap` releases an object as soon as it's not referred to anywhere else.  If there are "threads using an object," that object won't be released from the `WeakHashMap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw it all away and use a `java.util.WeakHashMap.` It already does exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I will do it! Its much less hard to deal with!

Answer (score 3):

I put together a working example for you that may help you with your issue.  I made Main a junit test to make it easy to run in your favorite IDE or elsewhere.

A couple of points to note.

A CountDownLatch was added so that all threads would complete before the executor service was shutdown and the result printed out.

Elem uses an AtomicInteger so the synchronized block is no longer necessary.

The most important fix to the code was to increment the counter in the constructor of the Sum class so that the Elem wasn't removed from the map until each thread had a chance to process.  Otherwise, it was possible for a thread to run all the way through and remove the Elem before other threads got a chance to execute.

-- Patrick

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import org.junit.Test;

public class Main
{
    @Test
    public void testExecute() throws Exception
    {
        int threadCount = 20;
        final CountDownLatch threadsCompleteLatch = new CountDownLatch( threadCount );

        Map<String, Elem> saldos = new ConcurrentHashMap<>( threadCount, 0.9f, 1 );
        AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger( 0 );
        Elem element = new Elem();
        saldos.put( "saldo", element );

        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( threadCount );

        try
        {
            for ( int i = 0; i < threadCount; ++i )
            {
                exec.execute( new Sum( threadsCompleteLatch, counter, saldos ) );
            }

            threadsCompleteLatch.await();
            exec.shutdown();

            System.out.println( "got elem: " + saldos.get( "saldo" ) + " counter: " + counter );
            System.out.println( "resulting element: " + element );
        }
        catch ( Exception ex )
        {
            exec.shutdownNow();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

class Elem
{
    private final AtomicInteger saldo = new AtomicInteger( 1000 );

    public int add( int value )
    {
        return saldo.getAndAdd( value );
    }

    int getSaldo()
    {
        return saldo.get();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Elem{ " +
                "saldo=" + saldo.get() +
                " }";
    }
}

class Sum implements Runnable
{
    private final Random rand = new Random();

    private final CountDownLatch latch;
    private final AtomicInteger counter;
    private final Map<String, Elem> saldos;

    Sum( CountDownLatch latch, AtomicInteger counter, Map<String, Elem> saldos )
    {
        this.latch = latch;
        this.saldos = saldos;
        this.counter = counter;
        counter.incrementAndGet();
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        int randomValue = rand.nextInt( 1000 );
        Elem element = saldos.get( "saldo" );

        if ( randomValue % 2 != 0 )
        {
            randomValue = -randomValue;
        }

        int saldoLido = element.add( randomValue );
        int saldoAtual = element.getSaldo();
        System.out.println(
                "saldo lido: " + saldoLido + " somado: " + randomValue + " saldo atual: " + (saldoAtual) + " " + System.currentTimeMillis() );

        if ( counter.decrementAndGet() == 0 )
        {
            saldos.remove( "saldo" );
        }

        latch.countDown();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank so much for your solution! I didn't know java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch ! :)

Comment: @LucasBatistussi Hard to see why this would be preferable to something already built-in to the JDK.

Comment: Yep! And this is for a pre-specified number of threads.... (constructor int)! I need for a undefined number of threads. And this approach makes threads wait until all others end. I think this have a overhead.... (keep many threads waiting for each element of the Map to be released is expensive no?)

Comment: @Patrick Nothing against your answer of course, good work. +1

Comment: @EJP.  Using a WeakHashMap is not going to work in this case, it more suited to be used as a cache.  The VM may decide to remove data from a WeakHashMap at anytime it so chooses, therefore it is not a good fit for this problem.  It works great as a cache though, where the data is temporary and if the value isn't in the cache it can be retrieved elsewhere.

Comment: @LucasBatistussi.  This example is a bit contrived to illustrate how to solve the problem you posed.  The CountdownLatch and waiting at the end is there just so that the main thread will wait till the other threads have processed before printing out the answer.  That wouldn't likely be necessary in a real solution.  Also, the only thread that waits is the main thread via the CountdownLatch.  The rest of the threads merely reduce the value of the latch when they are complete.  When the latch hits 0, the wait() method called by the main thread completes and the results are printed out.